# Nested objects data modeling for cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am using `spring data cassandra` and having trouble understanding how the data model should be. I understand that cassandra tables are generally denormalized so that means if I have a customer object that looks like this

```
{
  name: "Test Customer",
  address: {
    city: "New york",
    state: "NY"
  }
}
```

The corresponding POJOs would like this

```
@Table
public class Customer {
  @PrimaryKey //just using this as key for this example
  private String name;
  private Address address;
}

public class Address {
  private String city;
  private String state;
}
```

So I want to store only the customer objects but have some way to retrieve the address object associated with the customer object. What are some of the common strategies to handle this.

Should I be using the composite/compound key in some way or create a separate POJO where I can store attributes from both objects in a denormlized form or some other way. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra tables are created on the query which you want to perform (Query driven model).
So please share the query or set of queries which you want to perform on table.

Comment: The query would to retrieve customers by name. So something as simple as `select * from customers where name = 'Customer Name'` but the returned data should include information about the customer as well as the address information so it can be populated on the Customer java object

Comment: create table Customer(
  Customer_id uuid, 
  name text,
  address map<text, text>
  primary key ((name),Customer_id)
);

Above table can be used